# Words Starting With the Vowel "I"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels, vowel-length

The word of the day in Merriam-Webster's daily post was "Itinerant."

Words that start with the letter "I" most often have a short, or informally, a soft vowel sound, if two consonants follow the letter "I." Many well used exceptions, such as if, in, and it.

Words such as intelligent, inconsolable, imbecile, irresistible, and most others follow this rule.

On the other hand, words such as itinerary, isolated, idol, ideal, and others give a long, or informally, a hard vowel sound.

Simply put, as an English language teacher in Canada, is there an English rule that could help a person newly learning the English language that would avail a more straightforward answer to this question?

Comment: Why did you delete and repost this question? (This one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558775/words-starting-with-the-vowel-i) You shouldn’t do that: instead edit your original question.

Comment: Yes Laurel. I agree with your assertion. Though, I botched it up so badly, to be perfectly honest, I was embarrassed.

Comment: I should have composed the question correctly, to the best of my ability in the first place. Minor mistakes are easily edited. The way I worded the question was completely incorrect.

Comment: Don't you think this is exactly the kind of question for which the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange was created?

Comment: Sorry, as I wasn't aware of the 'ELL,' Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I am quite  new to StackExghange English Language & Usage. . Please excuse my ignorance with such matters.

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules that I'm aware of. I suspect the long vowel/diphthong is because of *Open Syllable Lengthening*. i-so-late, i-dol, i-deal, i-ti-ne-rant etc.

Comment: 'Iran' and 'ideological' show that rules are going to be hard to find.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Many people pronounce 'Iran' with a hard I, so it's only a partial exception. But the most hard and fast rule about English is that there are no hard and fast rules. There are some rules that are pretty good, you just have to learn a handful of  exceptions.

Comment: @Barmar The fact that "Many people pronounce 'Iran' with a hard I" (and many don't) illustrates precisely my point about rules being at best rules of thumb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought you were just using them as counterexamples to the rule he mentioned in the question.

Comment: 'Rules are going to be hard to find.' ?

Comment: English is infamous for its spelling bearing little relationship to its pronunciation.